# Matlab 3D interpolation

Tags: matlab, matrix, interpolation

I have 3 matrices(129x129) corresponding to x, y and z coordinates. I used the function mesh

```
mesh(x,y,z);
```

to plot the corresponding figure. It comes out to be a sphere. Now, I have another set of x, y, z(again 129) which gives a different sphere. What I want is to use interpolation in MATLAB to obtain the figures that come in between. I looked at the function [`interp3`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp3.html) in MATLAB but could not figure out what to do with it.

Comment: if your question indeed refers to surface evolution rather than interpolation, it would be best if you edit the title, the tags and the question accordingly, so other people would be able to access it more easily.

Answer (score 4):

It seems like you are interested in the *evolution* of the surface `z(x,y)` from one surface `z0` to another `z1`. I would suggest the following process

```
 T = 5; % number of "time steps" from z0 to z1
 t = linspace( 0, 1, T );
 for ii = 1 : T
     zt = t(ii).*z1 + (1-t(ii)).*z0;
     mesh( x, y, zt ); title( sprintf( 'time %d', ii ) );
     drawnow;
     pause(1); wait a sec
 end
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. How do I see both the figures in the same plot?

Comment: @ksingh you may use `subplot` to see several plots in the same figure

Comment: @ksingh BTW I assumed the underlying `x` and `y` do not change over time. If this is not the case, you might want to do the same trick with `x` and `y` as well: `xt = t(ii).*t1 + (1-t(ii)),*t0;` and `yt=t(ii).*y1 + (1-t(ii)).*y0;` and then `subplot(2,3,ii);mesh(xt,yt,zt);`